# Select one of each result from the following query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which catches the serial number in column `serial` and also what date that serial was captured using the `started` column I'm running the following query:

```
 SELECT * FROM spin
            WHERE `serial` in (
            SELECT `serial` from spin group by `serial`
            HAVING count(*) > 1
            ) ORDER BY started DESC
```

What this query is doing is selecting all the times a serial number is duplicated and returning them all but I want to alter this query so it returns only the latest result for each multiple item.

Answer (score 2):

This is the proper way to get what you want:

```
select s.*
from spin s join
     (select serial, max(started) as maxs
      from spin
      group by serial
     ) ss
     on s.serial = ss.serial and s.started = ss.maxs
order by started;
```

It finds the most recent date in a subquery and used `join` to get the matching record.

Comment: Good answer. This is something I like better in Oracle, where you can keep the query and simply entend it to look for `where (serial, started) in (select serial, max(started) ...`. It would be great if other dbms and the SQL standard adopted this feature.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . In Oracle, you would use the ANSI standard `row_number()` and not bother at all with this construct.